# How can I protect against junction-based TOCTOU issues in C#?

Tags: c#, race-condition, secure-coding

I would like to protect against TOCTOU issues with Junctions in C#. I am serving up files from  certain directories. These directories may be SMB/CIFS shares or local drives of whatever filesystem (but most likely NTFS).

Given my understanding of the issue, the following should protect me from it:

1. Open the File using `File.Open(foo, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)` This should prevent anything from modifying the file or the directory structure above it. I will need to catch `FileNotFoundException` in case the file was removed in between the `File.Exists` check and the `File.Open`.
2. Move up the directory structure, checking that each folder is not a junction until I reach the root folder.

I'm not worrying about file symlinks due to the fact that file symlinks require elevated administrative access to create, and if the attacker already has elevated administrative access to the local machine, they most likely have already fully compromised it.

I don't believe that I have to worry about CIFS, since my investigation of the matter leads me to believe that it is not possible to create symlinks on CIFS, unless the client supports the Unix extensions (which Windows does not).

As far as I know, all other filesystems that are supported by Windows do not support symlinks.

Comment: Junctions require elevated privilges as well - what exactly are you worried about?

Comment: @Eugen Rieck: They don't seem to require elevated privileges to me. `mklink /j foo bar` works perfectly well even in a non-elevated command prompt.

Comment: I stand corrected. This makes your question clear to me.